# How to insert a new line after the first line in a file that is similar to it

Tags: awk, columns

I converted csv file into columns, I want now to add dashes under each label of the first row (as it was underlined). with the dashed lines equal to the length of each label (labels may be composed of more than a word)

Here is an example:

```
Full name     age    country
---------     ---    -------
```

Comment: How did you convert the file to columns? In particular, how are the fields *delimited*? How can we tell that `Full name` is one label, not two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear exactly where you want to add dashes — how do you know that the space between “Full” and “name” isn't a column separator? To add dashes below every non-space character, you can use this awk one-liner:

```
awk '{print} NR==1 {gsub(/[^\t ]/, "-"); print}'
```

To add dashes below spaces but not below tabs:

```
awk '{print} NR==1 {gsub(/[^\t]/, "-"); print}'
```

To add dashes below everything except whitespace and also below lone spaces:

```
awk '{print} NR==1 {gsub(/[^ \t]/, "-"); while (sub(/- -/, "---")) {}; print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file was a comma separated file, then this code would do what you need during your initiall conversion from comma separated to spaces separated and would handle fields separated by spaces correctly since the delimiter is comma:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=" "}; 
NR==1{ 
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
       {
         dashes=gensub(/./,"-","G",$i);
         (h1 =="")?h1=$i:h1=h1 OFS $i;
         (h2=="")?h2=dashes:h2=h2 OFS dashes;
        };
       {print h1;print h2}
     }
NR>1{ 
     $1=$1;print
     }' <<<$'name1,name2,full name3,name4\nvalue1,value2,value3,value4'

name1 name2 full name3 name4
----- ----- ---------- -----
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

If your file is space separated then is hard to handle fields with spaces.
In reality those spaced fields like "full name" will be handled as two different fields.

By adjusting `BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}` on previous code and by feeding to awk a space separated file will print

```
name1 name2 full name3 name4
----- ----- ---- ----- -----
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

Tip: To generate as many dashes as each field length , i just insert the same field (i.e name1) on a second header line bellow original header line and substitute each character of each field with a dash. This yelds to a dashed string of equal length to each main header field (i.e name1 becomes ----- with gensub function)